# Cloudflare Hates TBB v7? (Not Duplicate)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, linux, captcha, cloudflare

What was the previous TBB version doing that I wasn't seeing so many Cloudflare captchas? Something in the UA or tweaked in about:config perhaps? All I know is TBB v6.x.x was able to view sites behind cloudflare. What happened?

Answer (score 1):

> What was the previous TBB version doing that I wasn't seeing so many
>   Cloudflare captchas?

According to these two comments from [arma](https://blog.torproject.org/comment/269009#comment-269009) and [gk](https://blog.torproject.org/comment/268994#comment-268994), the fix was on Cloudflare's side, and they haven't updated it for Tor Browser 7.0.

> Apparently Cloudflare had done some hack on their side to handle Tor
>   Browser better (i.e. trigger fewer false positives), but they haven't
>   updated it for Tor Browser 7.0. We hear they're in the process of
>   updating it. Soon I hope!

[gk](https://blog.torproject.org/comment/268994#comment-268994):

> The graphical passwords (I assume you mean things like "Select all the
>   cars"-style puzzles) are provided by Cloudflare. They are working on a
>   fix for this problem. It should be ready next week if all goes well.
>   Not sure how long it will take to get it rolled out globally, though.